# respond to any other element, but specified with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is how you respond to element clicked:

```
$("#buy-wrapper").click(function(){});
```

I would like to respond if any element, but the `#buy-wrapper` is clicked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can have events on `classes`, `element` or event on `document`. Please be specific and provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the not selector

```
$(":not(#buy-wrapper)").click(function(){});
```

Comment: This will have very huge impact. Let OP be specific. Like if `buy-wrapper` is a button, then we can suggest `$('button')` or a class. That will have little less impact